# Disambiguation of nested notes in eledmac

Tags: eledmac

In relation to the recent `\sameword`-feature in `eledmac`, what do I do when samewords are nested like this:

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
\edtext{in \edtext{\sameword{parte}}{\Bfootnote{partibus \textbf{A}.}} autem 
oculi compatiuntur, et ideo in \sameword{parte} corporis in mulieribus}{\lemma{in
\sameword{parte} -- mulieribus}\Bfootnote{\emph{om.} \textbf{E}.}}, sicut et 
ceterae partes corporis.
\pend

\endnumbering
```

I don't know if I should mark one or more of these with `[inlemma]`, but as it is here, it results in the following output in the apparatus.

```
1 in parte999 – mulieribus ]
```

Comment: Indeed you should use [inlemma] as explained in the handbook. However, there is still a bug with \sameword + nested notes. Please open an issue on github.

Comment: For future reference, see the Github issue at https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been solved with eledmac 1.23.0